# Common Expression Language in Workload Identity Federation of GitHub Actions not working as expected

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, workload-identity, common-expression-language

I am using a CEL expression for setting conditions on the Service Account usage of a Workload Identity Federation provider for GitHub Actions.

Here is the expression

```
(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && (assertion.event_name=='pull_request' || assertion.event_name=='workflow_dispatch') && assertion.job_workflow_ref.startsWith('MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml') && assertion.ref.startsWith('refs/heads/rule/'))
```

I am creating a Pull Request from a branch named `rule/lala2`. However the authentication fails "due to attribute condition"

If I remove the last statement, i.e. `assertion.ref.startsWith('refs/heads/rule/')` it works.

What am I missing here?